# Javascript Loop throug json with different key for same object structure

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm building a slider with the images taken from a json, this is the json structure

```
{  
    "info":[  
    {  
        "slide1":[  
            {  
                "title":"Title 1"
            },
            {  
                "subTitle":"sub title 1"
            },
            {  
                "image":"assets/img/image1.jpg"
            }
        ]
    },
    {  
        "slide2":[  
            {  
                "title":"Title 2"
            },
            {  
                "subTitle":"sub title 2"
            },
            {  
                "image":"assets/img/image2.jpg"
            }
        ]
    },
    {  
        "slide3":[  
            {  
                "title":"Title 3"
            },
            {  
                "subTitle":"sub title 3"
            },
            {  
                "image":"assets/img/image3.jpg"
            }
        ]
    }
    ]
}
```

My problem is that the slides have all the same structure but different keys, how could I loop inside this structure?
Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My problem is that the slides have all the same structure but
>   different keys, how could I loop inside this structure?

Something like

```
obj.info.forEach( function( item ){ //iterate info
  var slideName = Object.keys( item )[0]; //get the first key from each item
  var slideObj = item[ slideName ];

  //logic to build slider from the slideObj

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there isn't any problem with looping because you have an array. The only caveat would be get the key of the object a priori unknown, but you can get it throw the *Object.keys* method.

```
var obj= {  
    "info":[  
    {  
        "slide1":[  
            {  
                "title":"Title 1"
            },
            {  
                "subTitle":"sub title 1"
            },
            {  
                "image":"assets/img/image1.jpg"
            }
        ]
    },
    {  
        "slide2":[  
            {  
                "title":"Title 2"
            },
            {  
                "subTitle":"sub title 2"
            },
            {  
                "image":"assets/img/image2.jpg"
            }
        ]
    },
    {  
        "slide3":[  
            {  
                "title":"Title 3"
            },
            {  
                "subTitle":"sub title 3"
            },
            {  
                "image":"assets/img/image3.jpg"
            }
        ]
    }
    ]
};


for(var i in obj.info){
   var slide = obj.info[i];
   var keys = Object.keys(slide);
   for(var j in keys ){
      var elements = slide[keys[j]];
      for (var k0 in elements){
         var element = elements[k0];
         var element_keys = Object.keys(slide);
         for(var k1 in element_keys ){
          //Here you have the child element
          console.log(element[element_keys[k1]]);
         }
      }  

   }
}
```

By the way, a better structure with objects instead of arrays would be easier to loop.

Answer (score 0):

```js
data = {  
    "info":[  
    {  
        "slide1":[  
            {  
                "title":"Title 1"
            },
            {  
                "subTitle":"sub title 1"
            },
            {  
                "image":"assets/img/image1.jpg"
            }
        ]
    },
    {  
        "slide2":[  
            {  
                "title":"Title 2"
            },
            {  
                "subTitle":"sub title 2"
            },
            {  
                "image":"assets/img/image2.jpg"
            }
        ]
    },
    {  
        "slide3":[  
            {  
                "title":"Title 3"
            },
            {  
                "subTitle":"sub title 3"
            },
            {  
                "image":"assets/img/image3.jpg"
            }
        ]
    }
    ]
}

for(slide in data['info']){
  for(slideName in data['info'][slide]){
    title=data['info'][slide][slideName][0]['title'];
    subTitle=data['info'][slide][slideName][1]['subTitle'];
    image=data['info'][slide][slideName][2]['image'];

    document.write('slideName: '+slideName+'<br>');
    document.write('title: '+title+'<br>');
    document.write('subTitle: '+subTitle+'<br>');
    document.write('image: '+image+'<hr>');
  }
}
```

note that this is just for your current structure, and your structure is fix like that.